# ASP.NET MVC - Get Invoked Action Attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Given a string for an action name and controller and a RouteValueDictionary for the route values how do i return any attributes applied to the action which should be invoked?

I'd appreciate if someone could help. Thanks

Comment: `Type.GetType(<yourcontrollerName>).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == <yourActionName>).Attributes` would give you all the attributes of the action(s) corresponding to the name in the controller. You should be able to get the right Action (saying you have two methods with same name, one for GET, one for POST) playing with the RouteValueDictionary keys  / values... A little bit more context should help.

Comment: I figured there would be a method in the core to do this as obviously ASP.NET MVC has to to handle this themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to come up with the following:

```
protected IList<string> GetNamespaces(string area, RouteCollection routes) {
    return routes.OfType<Route>()
        .Where(r => r.DataTokens != null)
        .Where(r => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(area) && r.DataTokens["area"] == null) ||
            (r.DataTokens["area"] != null && r.DataTokens["area"].ToString() == area))
        .SelectMany(r => (IEnumerable<string>)r.DataTokens["Namespaces"])
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
}

public IList<Type> GetControllerTypes() {
    // Note you may wish to improve this to select from all the referenced assemblies aswell
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes()
        .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract)
        .ToList();
}

public Type GetControllerType(string controller, string area) {
    // Get the namespaces for the area
    var namespaces = GetNamespaces(area, RouteTable.Routes);

    // Return the controller type that matches a namespace and controller name
    return GetControllerTypes()
        .Single(t => t.Name == controller + "Controller"
            && namespaces.Any(n => n == t.Namespace));
}
```

Now you just have to say the following to get the type:

```
var type = GetControllerType("Admin", "Blog");
```

From that you can easily get the action or any attributes applied using reflection.

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

As @nfplee solution you can get controller by area and controller name but remember it may return  `Sequence contains no matching element` exception except you mention proper namespace in Register Routes. Add namespace to main registerroutes in RouteConfig just as any areas in RegisterArea method.

Hope this is useful.

Good Luck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).